# Call Mysql function from Slim Framework

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, slim

I'm trying to call a function I created in MySQL using the Slim framework.
This is my function in DBHandler.php:

```
public function validarSincronismo($pCnpj, $pLogin, $pImei){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT sincronizar(?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $pCnpj, $pLogin, $pImei);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

And this is the function in my index.php:

```
$app->post('/validar', function() use ($app) {
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $cnpj =    $app->request->post('cnpj');    
    $login = $app->request->post('login');
    $imei = $app->request->post('imei');
    $msg = $db->validarSincronismo($cnpj, $login, $imei);                 
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["message"] = $msg;
    echoRespnse(201, $response);
});
```

And I'm getting the following error in `phperror.log`:

```
[17-Sep-2015 21:12:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\MAMP\htdocs\test\include\DbHandler.php on line 69
```

I tried using `CALL sincronizar(?,?,?);` But it doesn't execute the SQL function.

Comment: Hey @Tiago, welcome to S.O. Does that query run correctly when you execute it directly in your database? Have you tried to debug the contents of `$stmt` var? You can add a `var_dump($stmt)` just after the declaration line to do so. BTW, I'm assuming you are using MySQLi, correct?

Comment: Is sincronizar a function, table or procedure?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen `sincronizar()` is a function which returns a char(50).

Comment: Hi @GustavoStraube, yes I am using MySQLi. I tried debugging the contents of $stmt var, as you suggested, and it returns a bool(false). If I change the SQL statement to `CALL sincronizar()` instead of `SELECT sincronizar()` when calling my SQL function, it returns the following: `object(mysqli_stmt)#40 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(3) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) } {"error":false,"message":false}`

Comment: @TiagoPires, I think you have to start replacing `SELECT` by `CALL` in your query. After that, how are you checking if the function is being executed or not? What does your function do? Does it change some data over your tables?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @GustavoStraube and @NorbertvanNobelen for taking the time and looking into my question! I was able to call my SQL function using `SELECT sincronizar()`. The problem was that I had created the function in the wrong database. My bad! :/

So my final and working code looks as follows:

Function in DBHandler.php

```
public function validarSincronismo($pCnpj, $pLogin, $pImei){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT sincronizar(?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $pCnpj, $pLogin, $pImei);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    // Returns a message
    return $result;
}
```

Function in index.php

```
$app->post('/validar', function() use ($app) {
            $db = new DbHandler();
            $cnpj = $app->request->post('cnpj');    
            $login = $app->request->post('login');
            $imei = $app->request->post('imei');
            $msg = $db->validarSincronismo($cnpj, $login, $imei);                 
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = $msg;
            echoResponse(201, $response);
        });
```